# ng-class expression: merge condition and class name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, directive, ng-class

Supposing I have 3 variables (they can change its value):

```
$scope.A = 'one';
$scope.B = true;
$scope.C = false;
```

- `<div ng-class="A"></div>` renders `<div class="one">`
- `<div ng-class="{'two': B, 'three': C}"></div>` renders `<div class="two">`

How can I merge a variable and a expression to render `<div class="one two">`? Do I have to write a function?

I tried:  `<div ng-class="[A, {'two': B}, {'three': C}]"></div>`

Comment: Did you try this ? : <div class="{{A}}" ng-class="{'two': B, 'three': C}"></div>

Comment: wouldn't that overwrite the `class` attribute? not sure.

Comment: Gonna give two way of doing this

Comment: @TheWarlock Added a plunker which show that it works ;)

Comment: even i tried a plunker and upvoted  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got two solutions in my mind :

See them working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aZ2X8823X6v4k3RCt6RN?p=preview)

**First :  in HTML**

```
<div class="aclass {{A}}" ng-class="{'two': B, 'three': C}"></div>
```

**Second : With a function**

```
<div class="aclass" ng-class="getClasses()"></div>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.A = 'one';
$scope.B = true;
$scope.C = false;

$scope.getClasses = function(){
    var classes = "";
    classes += $scope.A;
    if($scope.B) classes += " two ";
    if($scope.C) classes += " three ";
    return classes;
}
```

Both will result in

```
<div class="aclass one two"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know how add (or not) a `$scope.A` class name if `$scope.B` is `true` (or `false`)? For example, if `A='something'` and `B=true` -> `<div class="something">` and if `A='other'` and `B=false` -> `<div></div>`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just use the second solution in this case. You'll be free to add as much logic as you want. if($scope.B) classes += $scope.A

Comment: I suppose you mean that it's not possible to do inline html. Am I right?